# Why can't I import this Haskell module/package?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I installed the `SourceGraph` package using cabal:
`cabal install SourceGraph`
It was installed perfectly without any errors.
Now, I've created a file called `Test.hs` to test if I am able to import this package and use it. These are the contents of `Test.hs`:

```
    module Test where

    import SourceGraph

    main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

When I do `ghc Test` I get the following error:
`Could not find the module 'SourceGraph'`

When I do `ghc-pkg list` I cannot find `SourceGraph` in the list, though all dependencies installed along with it are visible.
I checked in `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\cabal\packages\hackage.haskell.org` and I can see the `SourceGraph` folder there.
But there is no `.conf` file for `SourceGraph` in `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-7.10.2\package.conf.d`.
Also, all the `.log` files in `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs` have a line `In-place registering packagename-version...` at the end, but `SourceGraph-0.7.0.7,log` doesn't.

Help please?

[System Specifications: GHCi version 7.10.2, Cabal Version: 1.22.4.0, OS: Windows 8 Pro, Processor: Intel Core i5 (64 bit)]

Comment: *SourceGraph* is not a library; it is an application. Cf. [its documentation at Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph). When you do `cabal instal foo`, `foo` is not a module, but a package. Library packages, in turn, *contain* modules which you can import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SourceGraph` is not a library, it is a program to be run on the command line.

See it's [hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph)

There it says (with added `$`s for the bash prompt):

> To use SourceGraph, call it as either:
>
> ```
> $ SourceGraph path/to/Foo.cabal
> ```
>
> Or, if your project doesn't use Cabal, then there is limited support for > using an overall module from your program/library:
>
> ```
> $ SourceGraph path/to/Foo.hs
> ```

Comment: Oh God. I cannot believe I was so stupid. I tried it and fixed it. I was able to run run it, but alas! There's a problem in the package itself. Sad. Really sad.  
But thank you anyways.

Comment: Edit: I got it to work. The problem was that I had to install graphviz for windows using the installer and update the PATH variable to add the folder that contained dot.exe.